# SELECT Name WHERE LevenshteinFunction ReturnValue > 80 AND also select the ReturnValue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have the following SQL-Select Statement:

```
SELECT [Name], 
       [No_] 
  FROM [Table] 
 WHERE dbo.fn_Levenshtein('Mobel Meller', [Name]) > 80
```

- **Then i get**: Name, No
- **What i want**: Name, No, ReturnValue

My solution is the following, but i don't wanna call the function for each record **two** times because of performance... Is there an other way to do this?

```
SELECT [Name], 
       [No_], 
       dbo.fn_Levenshtein('Mobel Meller', [Name]) 
  FROM [Table] 
 WHERE dbo.fn_Levenshtein('Mobel Meller', [Name]) > 80
```

**Edit**: I'm not shure, if it really does run twice. And also not how to check that.

**Edit2**: My ExecutionPlan for my second Statement: [image: Execution Plan]
But i Can't read this ExecutionPlan.. So does it run Twice or not?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually running the algorithm twice per row?

Comment: Can [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896829/sql-use-a-calculated-fields-from-the-select-in-the-where-clause) be of any help?

Comment: @Phylogenesis No i'm not sure, but i also don't know to how to check if it does run twice..

Comment: Try running it and looking at the execution plan. Also, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260281/best-way-to-use-a-scalar-udf-that-needs-to-appear-in-the-select-and-where-clause the use of a CTE may be what you need if it is being called twice

Comment: @RichAndrews I did upload this ExecutionPlan just for you =)

Comment: I will bow to other query optimisation geniuses out there but I would say it looks like it is only being computed once for the where clause and then the result being reused in the select based on the select cost of 0% verses the compute & filter cost of 4%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, the below is the CTE version of your query...

```
WITH Result ([Name], [No_], [Distance]) AS (
SELECT [Name], 
       [No_], 
       dbo.fn_Levenshtein('Mobel Meller', [Name]) 
  FROM [Table] 
)

SELECT * 
FROM Result
WHERE [Distance] > 80
```

Adapted from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260281/best-way-to-use-a-scalar-udf-that-needs-to-appear-in-the-select-and-where-clause). I particularly like the point that even if is only being run once the CTE version feels a little more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT tb.Name, 
       tb.[No_], 
       Result 
  FROM [Table] tb
       CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_Levenshtein('Mobel Meller', tb.[Name]) AS Result
 WHERE Result > 80;
```

Comment: Maybe this would work also but i already found working ways..Thanks Anyway!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT [Name], 
       [No_], 
       dbo.fn_Levenshtein('Mobel Meller', [Name]) as [rtnval]
  FROM [Table]
) as RTNTBL 
 WHERE [rtnval] > 80
```

Comment: How it is *different from/better than*  already posted solutions?

Comment: I was typing when the last post about the "having" statement was posted,, I apologize, im a noob

Comment: @Alexander because, it does not need an extra column maybe?